# VS Code doesn't allow drag and drop files from the File Explorer (MacOs)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, macos-high-sierra

I want to drag-and-drop files from VSCode window (File Explorer view) to my FTP program (Cyberduck) on MacOS High Sierra, but somehow it doesn't work.

Any idea why, is it a feature or just some settings? (I have all the drag-and-drop settings ticked in the Settings)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the changes I made from Settings menu did not update settings.json file in Users folder so I copied the setting ID and value using "Copy Setting as Json" to the settings.json file directly. After then, I had no problem with drag & drop file.